# Ext JS store sync change method

Tags: ajax, post, extjs, store, put

Is it possible to change the dafault methos POST that a store snync() request uses.

I have tried the following but it did not work. I would like to change the method from POST to PUT.

I am aware I can write a custom Ajax request but is there a way to do this with the store sync() functionallity?

```
    store.sync({
        method: 'PUT',
        scope:this,

        callback: function(batch, options){
        },
        success : function(batch, options) {
        },
        failure :  function(batch, options) {
        }

    });
}
```

I have also tried this kind of approach without success:

```
store.getProxy().method =  'PUT';
```

Answer (score 0):

In the proxy config for your store, you can configure the api to make specific request methods for each type of action.

For example:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    actionMethods: {
        create: 'POST',
        read: 'GET',
        update: 'POST',
        destroy: 'POST'
    },
    batchActions: false,
    api: {
        create: 'foo/sample.json',
        read: 'bar/sampleB.json',
        update: 'test/test.json',
        destroy: 'admin/testa.json'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json'
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The code above gets generated from Sencha Architect, but if you are not using Architect you could define the api actions on your REST proxy like this:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    api: {
        create: {url: 'foo/sample.json', method: 'POST'},
        read: {url: 'bar/sampleB.json', method: 'GET'},
        update: {'test/test.json', method: 'PUT'},
        destroy: {'admin/testa.json', method: 'POST'}
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using an rest proxy and cannot find this settings

Comment: Ok just re-reading the docs, and I think the problem for you here is that the HTTP verbs are automatically generated by ExtJS if you use a REST proxy. If you want full control so you can set the actions like in my example I shared, you would need to use the AJAX proxy type. You could actually try adding a custom 'actionMethods' property to your Rest proxy config in Architect and then set the methods to PUT in an object declaration, again as per my example.

Comment: FYI: actionMethods do work for REST proxy on ExtJS 6.2.0.